# Display window not popping because something wrong with debugging code

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-2017

when i run this code in MVS 2017 or on Jupyter lab/notebook, it isn't debugging.
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
rd = cv2.imread('images/road.png')              
rd_copy = np.copy(rd)                           




def canny(image):

    gray_rd = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    blur_rd = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_rd, (5,5),0)   
    canny_rd = cv2.Canny(blur_rd,50,150)

    return canny_rd


def region_of_interest(image):

    #height = image.shape[0]
    triangle = np.array([(405,1070),(1475,1070),(808,420)])
    mask = np.zeros_like(image)
    cv2.fillPoly(mask, triangle,255)

    return mask

canny_rd = canny(rd_copy)

#plt.imshow(canny_rd)
#plt.show()

cv2.namedWindow('ROAD PIC', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('ROAD PIC', region_of_interest(canny_rd))
#cv2.imshow('ROAD PIC', canny_rd)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but when i run the same code without calling the region_of_interest function, its debugging properly. Anything wrong with the way am calling or the way i have defined the region_of_interest function?

Answer (score 0):

`fillPoly` expects an array of polygon's as input, where a polygon is an array of points. You are currently inputting 1 polygon as an array of points. To put the triangle in an array you can put it in square brackets:
`cv2.fillPoly(mask, [triangle],255)`